# I want to set local-storage and qty increment in every click when product ID already exist in cart by Vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, shopping-cart

I made a shopping cart, where a product item gets added to the cart. When I click the product, it gets stored in a cart, but not local storage. I set it local-storage. When I click a product that already exists in the cart, I want to increment its quantity, but that's not happening. It adds another row instead, which I want to prevent.

Here is my component:

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div v-for="(product, id) in products" :key="id" class="col-xl-3 col-sm-6 mb-3 float-left">
                <div class="card o-hidden h-100">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-body-icon">
                        <i class="fas fa-fw fa-comments"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mr-5">{{product.name}}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer clearfix small z-1 form-group row" href="#">
                        <span class="float-left"><input type="text" v-model="product.qty" class="form-control form-control-sm mb-2"></span>
                        <strong class="float-right col-sm-6">
                            {{product.price}} TK
                        </strong>
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info float-right col-sm-6" @click="addToCart(product)">
                            <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <table class="table table-sm">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th>#SL</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Qty</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>L/T</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="(cart, i) in carts" :key="i">
                        <td>{{cart.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{cart.name}} </td>
                        <td class="text-right">{{cart.qty}}</td>
                        <td class="text-right">{{cart.price}}</td>
                        <td class="text-right">{{cart.price*cart.qty}}</td>
                        <td><button type="button" @click="removeProduct(i)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">x</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4" class="text-right font-weight-bold">Total</td>
                        <td class="text-right"> {{total}}/-</td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
            <div>
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info float-right">Checkout</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            products:[],
            carts:[],
        }
    },

    computed:{
        total(){
            var total = 0
            this.carts.forEach(cart => {
                total += parseFloat(cart.price * cart.qty)
            })
            return total
        },
    },

    mounted(){
        this.showProduct()
    },

    methods:{
        showProduct(){
            axios.get('api/pos')
            .then(res=>{
                this.products = res.data.data
            });
        },

        addToCart(product){
            this.carts.push(product)
        },

        removeProduct(i){
            this.carts.splice(i,1)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Here is the screenshot:
[image: this my output project screenshot. how to prevent it.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `addToCart()` just pushes another product into the cart without checking if it already exists.

To fix the problem, update that method to find the item, and increment the item's quantity if found. Otherwise, push another item into the cart:

```
addToCart(product) {
  if (this.carts.find(p => p.id === product.id)) {
    product.qty++
  } else {
    this.carts.push(product)
  }
}
```